# Excel Automate Edge with CDP Protocol - Error to Get Class Name

Tags: excel, vba, automation, microsoft-edge, cdp

I am new to VBA Excel, but I would like to be able to create a macro to automate Edge to retrieve information on a specific page.

The goal is to know if the ClassName "colHead w3" appears or not on the page in question, I put the link of the HTML file so that you can know the location of this class (internal link inaccessible elsewhere, I have not find another way to post it).

I use the .QuerySelector , .GetElementsByClassName and .GetElementsByCss

But either I receive the error message "Error 424: Object required" or the error passes and shows me the incorrect result.

This is the code i use for test :

```vb
Sub runedge()

    'Start Browser
    Dim objBrowser As clsBrowser
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Class As Object
    Dim pst As Long
    Set objBrowser = New clsBrowser
    objBrowser.start "edge"
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")

With ws
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

    'navigate
    Call objBrowser.navigate("link")
    
    objBrowser.wait till:="interactive"


    'Call objBrowser.jsEval("document.getElementsByName(""value"")[0].value=""test""")


    'run search
    'Call objBrowser.jsEval("document.getElementsByName(""search"")[0].click()")
    
    'wait till search has finished
    'objBrowser.wait till:="interactive"

On Error GoTo 0
 
    objBrowser.wait till:="interactive"

pst = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1

    If objBrowser.jsEval("Document.queryselector("".colHead.w3"")[0]") > 0 Then
        ws.Cells(pst, "D").Value = "Redeemed"
    Else
        ws.Cells(pst, "D").Value = "Free"
    End If


Next
End With

objBrowser.show

End Sub
```

HTML File Link : https://www.mediafire.com/file/aa7m16xyrmvrmvt/SearchResults.do.html/file

Thank you for help :)

Comment: Are you using https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5307593/Automate-Chrome-Edge-using-VBA ?

Comment: Yes i already use it but i still don't found solution for this issue

Comment: Where is `objBrowser` declared and created?

Comment: As i said before, my code are more complicated than this one i have post, but i have the issue only for the class name element (i edit my post with the full code)

Comment: No one have seen this issue before ?

Comment: I doubt there are many people here who've ever used that approach: most posts here on similar topics are using VBA with Selenium Basic.   This is the first post I recall where this library is mentioned.